# how to fix "Amazon S3 CORS configuration in django"

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i am having a problem implementing amazon S3 in my Django web app.i uploaded the media files in the s3 bucket. but whenever I visit the web app, the images
don't appear. and when I click open image in another location, then I get this message.
   "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

thanks.

CORS configurations in AWS3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Given that error, what makes you think this is a CORS issue?

Comment: Show us the XML returned by Amazon.

Comment: You should also remove your access keys from your question and rotate it asap.